# Deriving the variance of the Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a Bernoulli distribution, $\mu_X = p$. I can easily derive this from the general equation for mean of a discrete random variable:
$$
\mu_X=\sum_{i=1}^kx_iPr(X=x)
$$
$$
\mu_X=1(p)+0(1-p)=p
$$
I know that the variance of the Bernoulli distribution is supposed to be $\sigma_x^2=p(1-p)$. But I can not seem to derive that properly from the general equation for variance of a discrete random variable:
$$
\sigma_x^2=\sum_{i=1}^k(x_i-\mu_X)Pr(X=x_i)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=(x_0-p)(1-p)+(x_1-p)(p)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=(0-p)(1-p)+(1-p)(p)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=-p(1-p)+(1-p)(p)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=-p+p^2+p-p^2
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=0
$$
This is obviously incorrect; what am I doing incorrectly in my derivation?

Comment: You want the mean of the **squared** difference from the mean.

Comment: Consider the fact that for a random variable $X$, $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.

Comment: To put it another way: you're correctly computing $\mathbb E[X - \mu_X]$—but this quantity is always zero. (Can you see why?) You want to compute $\mathbb E[(X - \mu_X)^2]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\sigma_x^2=\sum_{i=1}^k(x_i-\mu_X)^\color{red}2Pr(X=x_i)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=(x_0-p)^\color{red}2(1-p)+(x_1-p)^\color{red}2(p)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=(0-p)^\color{red}2(1-p)+(1-p)^\color{red}2(p)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=p^\color{red}2(1-p)+(1-p)^\color{red}2(p)
$$
$$
\sigma_x^2=p(1-p)(p+1-p)=p(1-p)
$$

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to square: $$ \sigma_X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^2 (x_i-p)^2P(X=x_i) = p^2(1-p)+(1-p)^2p =p(1-p)$$

Answer (score 4):

By definition,

$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2%$$

Consider a success being a $1$ and a failure being a $0$.

Then we have

$$\begin{align*}
Var(X)
&=\sum_{x=0}^1(x^2)Pr(X=x)-\left(\sum_{x=0}^1(x)Pr(X=x)\right)^2\\\\
&=\left(1^2\cdot p + 0^2 (1-p)\right)-\left(1 \cdot p + 0 (1-p)\right)^2\\\\
&=p-p^2\\\\
&=p(1-p)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: "By definition ... " in almost every book I have ever taught out of, that isn't the definition so much as a simple theorem that is proved within a page or so of the definition. I am being pedantic of course, but I have often noticed problems when students forget the standard definition and remember only this instead. They seem to sometimes struggle with understanding what variance actually is, and are unable to prove the simplest things about it.

Comment: That's fair. I've used that formula so often to calculate variance that I forgot it isn't the definition

Answer (score 2):

Let $X\sim Ber(p)$. You've rightly shown that $E(X) = p$.

Now compute $E(X^2)$. That is,

$$\sum_{\ x\in R_x}x^2p_X(x) = 1^2\cdot p_X(1) + 0^2\cdot p_X(0) = p + 0 = p$$

Therefore, 
$$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = p - p^2 = p(1-p) $$

Comment: It may be faster to say that if $X=0$ or $1$ then $X^2=X$ and so $E[X^2]=E[X]$